# find out if an id exists in a layout used by RemoteViews / AppWidgets

Tags: android, android-appwidget

I want to have a flexible Appwidget which investigates which views are contained in the associated layout and which not. Normally I would use findViewByID to see if it returns any ID but that is not possible in appWidgets. How can I do this?

I tried context.getResources().getIdentifier(name, "id", context.getPackageName()) but this will always return a valid id because the id is defined by another layout file. I need to find out whether my current layout contains the id.

```
public class MyWidget extends AppWidgetProvider {
    static void updateAppWidget(Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager,
                                int appWidgetId) {                  
        String idName="idName";
        String layoutName="layoutName";

        RemoteViews views = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), Tools.getLayoutResource(context,layoutName));
        boolean idExistsInLayout=context.getResources().getIdentifier(name, "id", context.getPackageName());
    }
}
```

Comment: Why not just define a `ViewModel`/POJO class you can send to your Provider, which defines exactly what should and shouldn't be visible, so you can know unambiguously how you should be constructing your layout?

Comment: I want to use a smart app widget which investigates the layout and then it knows which components it need to calculate data for

Answer (score 1):

> How can I do this?

AFAIK, you can't. There is no API for this, and AFAIK the `RemoteViews` instance in your process does not even look at the layout resource. It just passes that ID, along with your other values, to the other process for rendering.

There is nothing stopping your own code from inflating the layout, then doing these sorts of checks against your inflated layout instead of the `RemoteViews`. This feels like swatting a fly with a Buick; I suspect that there are simpler solutions for whatever problem you are trying to solve.

Comment: ok but where to take the layoutinflator from when I have an appwidet onUpdate method?

Comment: @Alex: I do not understand the question. If you mean how do you create a `LayoutInflater` from your `onUpdate()` method, call `LayoutInflater.from(context)`. Again, I think that there will be a better solution than this.

Comment: works great, thanks. Actually the solution is pretty good. I have different layouts for a countdown and depending on what the layout offers the appwidget can now fill it with data. No need to track which layout needs which data now.